# How can you pass data from a parent route to a child route in Vue.js nested routes?

Tags: javascript, vue-router

I am trying to use nested routing in my Vue.js application. I have the routing working, however I cannot figure out how to pass data from a parent route down to a child route.

Basically, the parent route is going to retrieve an object that has properties. For each specific nested child route, I want to show one of the properties on that object.

For example, if I have the object below:

```
myDataObject : {name : "Foo" , profile : "Profile Data", posts : "Posts Data" }
```

I would like to pass the "profile" variable to the child route "/user/:id/profile". In the case of "/user/:id/posts", I would like to pass the "post" variable in.

I thought I could accomplish this using props, but I cannot find an example that fits with routing and what I tried does not seem to work.

Here is a link to a jsfiddle of what I am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/90q4sucj/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See the answer below for the correct answer**

> ! You can retrieve data by using services you create.  In the example given I've updated to follow the "fetch data after navigation" sample shown in the docs. It has a `userService` that will handle getting the user's profile.
>
> !    const userService = {
>           findProfile(id) { return 'Profile Data'; }
>       };
>   ! Then I updated the UserProfile component to get the profile when it's created and it watches the `$route` for changes.
>
> !    const UserProfile = { 
>         data() { return { profile: null } },
>         template: 'Profile {{ $route.params.id }} {{ profile }}',
>         methods: {
>           setProfile: function () {  this.profile =     userService.findProfile(this.$route.params.id); }
>         },
>         created: function () { this.setProfile(); },
>         watch: { '$route': 'setProfile' }
>       }
>
> ! As for passing it through like `props: []` I didn't see a way but that's probably a good thing because it could start getting pretty convoluted. Here you know explicitly where the user profile is coming from and don't need to follow a rabbit hole to figure it out.
>
> ! http://jsfiddle.net/90q4sucj/3/

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I think I understand you answer, however, can you clarify a few things? Am I incorrect on thinking that data should be passed down from a parent to a child? Instead the service should handle fetching data and then getting it to the nested routes?

Comment: Passing it from parent to child makes sense when you're not navigating to the child. If the child is used to compose the parent then you'd pass down properties. In this case the parent component User doesn't need the UserProfile component to do its job.

Comment: Also, you can make the UserService smart to limit API calls. Maybe when the parent User asks for the User you store that in a Map so its available locally. Of course that would require expiring cache in a certain amount of time so that you don't have stale data.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for correcting your answer, it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 21):

This is definitely doable with `props`.

**In parent component**

```
<template>
...
<router-view :profile="myDataObject.profile" />
...
</template>
```

**In child component**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "child",
  props: ["profile"]
...
```

Now, in your child component you may access the data by referring to `this.$props.profile`.

---

I am using this pattern with Vue 2.5.16. and Vue Router 3.0.1.

PS: A good option is to also use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org) for such scenarios.

Comment: Confirmed passing props still works with Vue 3 and Vue Router 4. Surprisingly couldn't find any reference to this in their docs, appreciate you posting this!